# Accessing subclass in base class... but different

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have a base class that has a subclass (could be a struct i suppose but not sure if it's appropriate) and a method.

```
class Base 
{
    protected class SubClass 
    {
        public string word;
        public int number;
    }

    protected void SomeMethod()
    {
        this.SubClass.word //this is where I'm struggling
    }
}
```

Then i have a couple child classes that implement my baseClass, instantiate the Base.SubClass and add some values to the instantiated class.

```
class ChildClass1 : Base
{
    public childSubClass = new SubClass();

    public void DoSomethingRidiculous()
    {
        childSubClass.word = "WhoFarted";
    }
} 

class ChildClass2 : Base
{
    public childSubClass = new SubClass();

    public void DoSomethingRidiculous()
    {
        childSubClass.word = "ItStinks";
    }
}
```

If possible, I would like to be able to get the value of SubClass.word from within the Base class.  I think that my attempt at implementing my idea is probably wrong.

Comment: Can you describe what your overall goal is? This is a fairly odd class structure.

Comment: Your terminology is rather confused. What you call a subclass is called a nested class. What you call a child class is a subclass.

Comment: @Oded thanks for clearing that up...you can probably tell i'm learning still.

Comment: @Matt Greer I'm still learning. I'm in the process of refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that you really need subclassing / class nesting. Just move out class `SubClass`  declaration and declare protected field/property of `SubClass` type instead.

```
public class SubClass 
{
   public string word;
   public int number;
}

public class Base 
{
    protected SubClass subClassInstance = new SubClass();

    protected void SomeMethod()
    {
        this.subClassInstance.word //this is where I'm struggling
    }
}
```

Then you can access `subClassInstance` inside both `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2`

Comment: I'm definitely doing it wrong. This was clear and concise. I think it's obvious I'm still learning, so thanks for straightening me out. Much appreciated!

Comment: Note (to the OP) that you could still nest `SubClass` inside of `Base` in this case.  You'd just access the base class's `subClassInstance` in the derived classes rather than instantiating it in them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The base class has no field or property of type `SubClass`, so you definitely cannot do what you propose directly.

One solution would be to add the field

```
public childSubClass = new SubClass();
```

to class `Base` itself. Is there a problem with this?

The other solution would be to use reflection to get the value of the field, assuming that the object you are reflecting on does have such a field. This is really far-fetched and while it might technically allow you to do what you propose, it has a very bad code smell.

Answer (score 1):

A base class can not (or *should* not) access members of derived classes, and usually not even *know* about derived classes (some exceptions apply, such as in the case of the State Pattern). If the base should have access to a member, it should be declared in the base. If derived classes should also be able to use that member, then mark the member as protected.

```
class Base
{
     protected Foo someFoo;

     void Frob()
     {
         // can access methods/properties of someFoo instance
     }
}

class Child 
{
    public Child() 
    {
        someFoo = new Foo(); // child can also access someFoo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're making a Sub Class instead of just making those two properties of the base class, but the reason you're having trouble with this line :

```
this.SubClass.word //this is where I'm struggling
```

is because you're not instantiating SubClass as a property of the base class.